# '_id' не существует при работе с SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, база-данных, sqlite

Почитал похожие ветки, но там создаются запросы более детального плана, а мне нужно пока просто вытащить курсор со всей таблицей.

злополучная строка с id (помимо прочих)

```
public static final String _ID = "_id";
```

база данных

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

  String sql = String.format("CREATE TABLE %1$s ( %2$s INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, %3$s TEXT, %4$s TEXT, %5$s TEXT, %6$s INTEGER, %7$s INTEGER)",
            TABLENAME, _ID, NAME, GENRE, COUNTRY, YEAR, RATE);
    db.execSQL(sql);
```

запрос

```
public class Handler {
    private DB helper;

    public Handler(Context context) {

        this.helper = new DB(context);
    }

public Cursor getOpenedItems(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
    return db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DB.TABLENAME, null);
}
```

установка курсора в адаптер (MainActivity)

```
        handler = new Handler(this);

    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.activity_main, handler.getOpenedItems(), from, to, CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Как видно я не вытаскиваю именно id с таблицы, и нет смысла делать что-то типа select myId as _id ... 
Но почему по-прежнему такая ошибка? _id присутствует в таблице, и вызывается со всем прочим...

Comment: ошибку нужно указать в том виде, в котором вы ее получаете, а не вольный перевод.

Comment: постараюсь в следующий раз. сейчас к сожалению ошибка уже исчезла. к сожалению - потому что я так и не понял по какой причине она неожиданно пропала.